# people over-twenty-one

Tags: adjectives

a. People over-twenty-one will have to pay full price.

b. Over-twenty-one people will have to pay full price.

c. Were there any people over-twenty-one who did not pay full price?

d. Were there any over-twenty-one people who did not pay full price?

In which of the above sentences 'over-twenty-one' is in the correct place?

I think if one heard (b) one might get the wrong impression that the intended meaning is that more than twenty-one people will have to pay full price. I am not sure the sentence works.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

AME speaker, I would say that both a and c are correct. This is a case where it's used as a set phrase (being a shortened form of "people over 21 years of age"). And because of that the "over-21 people" form simply does not work.

Comment: Personally, I think (c) makes more sense than (a), which I think should read "people over twenty-one..."

Comment: The first hyphen is wrong in both cases.

Comment: @Kate Bunting: agreed, I am blind and didn't even realize the hyphen is present in those cases.

Answer (score 1):

The question itself feels a bit off to me.

The correct options here would look like one of the following.

1. People over twenty-one will have to pay full price.
2. Were there any people over twenty-one who did not pay full price?

Just in case, we have [an explainer and quiz on word order here](https://grammarerror.com/intro/basics-a1-word-order).

UPD: This account is affiliated with grammarerror.com.

Comment: IT might be obvious from your username, but please read through [this](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/promotion) and please disclose your affiliation in your post (you can [edit] it).